# index.js:1 Material-UI: The key `selectLabel` provided to the classes prop is not implemented in ForwardRef(TablePagination)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to react and getting spammed with the same error in console after adding the following component.

Full Error:

> Material-UI: The key `selectLabel` provided to the classes prop is not implemented in ForwardRef(TablePagination).
> You can only override one of the following: root,toolbar,spacer,caption,selectRoot,select,selectIcon,input,menuItem,actions

I could not find a `selectLabel` anywhere in my project.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {DataGrid} from '@material-ui/data-grid'

const columns = [
  {field: '_id', headerName: 'ID'},
  {field: 'value', headerName: 'value', width: 300},
  {field: 'date', headerName: 'date', width: 600}
]

const ReadoutGrid = () => {

  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/readouts")
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((data) => setTableData(data))
 })

  return (
    <div style={{height: 700, width: '100%'}}>
      <DataGrid 
        
        getRowId={(row) => row._id}
        rows={tableData}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={12}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ReadoutGrid
```

Comment: Feels like a bug. Try to reproduce it in a codesnadbox and submit a bug. Are you using material-ui 4 or 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into this, too. It turns out to be due to a change in MaterialUI Core v4.12.1, as mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/2106

My fix was to change my `package.json` file so that the version was set to 4.11.4, like so:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.32"
  },
```

This should only be a temporary problem, though, as there is already a pull request to fix it.

Comment: Do we need to do something like install a new version of material ui core? or just directly edit the package.json and magic?

Comment: Edit your package.json and then run `yarn` or `npm install` again

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't find `selectLabel` anywhere in your app, that error is probably triggered by some library that has not been designed to work with mui v4.12.

In this case there is not much you can do, apart from:

- finding what library triggered that error -> then updating it
- downgrading to 4.11 as pointed out in another answer

**However**, if you manage to find `selectLabel` in some of your code `makeStyles`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
     // ..
  },
  someComponentYouWantedToStyle: {
     // ...
  },
}));
```

then to get rid of warning you can split that style declaration in two:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
     // ..
  },
}));

const useSomeComponentYouWantedToStyleStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
     // ...
  },
}));
```

This warning shows when `selectLabel` is used together with mui keys somewhere, then `selectLabel` is treated as a foreign key that does not exist on correct `classes` for some element, and here the warning is shown.